# implementation of Radix Sort on binary in C

Tags: arrays, c, radix-sort

I'm a bit lost on the implementation of a Radix sort on Binary Numbers. This is what I thought of so far but I'm not sure if I'm approaching this right. I understand how a Radix sort works and I know how to implement it on numbers in base 10. But needing to do it on binary numbers is throwing me off.

```
//count is amount of numbers in arr_bin

void sorter(int **arr_bin, unsigned int pos)
{
    unsigned int *bucket[2];
    bucket[0] = (unsigned int*) malloc(count * sizeof(unsigned int));
    bucket[1] = (unsigned int*) malloc(count * sizeof(unsigned int));
    for (int place = 31; place >= 31-pos; place--){
        unsigned int zero_count = 0;
        unsigned int one_count = 0;
        for (int p = 0; p < count; p++){
            if(arr_bin[p][place] == 0){
                bucket[0][zero_count] = ?; //I dont know what to set the buckets to 
                zero_count++;
            }
            else{
                bucket[1][one_count] = ?;
                one_count++;
            }

        }

    //Join the buckets to a new array?

    }
}
```

arr_bin is a 2d array consisting of the binary representation of the unsigned ints inputted, Since I cant have a string representation of them in this particular case. And pos is the largest place of any of the numbers. So for input of: 12,8,4. The array would be

00000000000000000000000000001100

00000000000000000000000000001000

00000000000000000000000000000100

pos = 4

I was thinking of setting buckets to the index of the arrays and then updating a new array from the buckets. And then I would just have a sorted array of indexes of the arr_bin? I dont know but thats as far as I got.

Edit: Thank you, using bitwise instead of arrays basically solved all my problems

Comment: You don't need a seperate array for bit representation. Jusst use bitwise-operators. for instance, `k & (1 << n)` gives the nth bit of integer `k`.

Comment: @Uduru Oh I haven't thought of that. So instead of using an array, I would loop through nth bit on each integer? I'll try that out.

Comment: It will be much faster to use base 256 (8 bits) instead of base 2 (1 bit).